# Qualcomm Atheros Bluetooh goes missing FREQUENTLY on ASUS ROG-GL502V

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth

Just wanted to help in trying to find a root cause of this issue.

ASUS ROG-GL502V
Windows 10

The issue and the solution is in this thread :
[Bluetooth Stopped Working in Windows 10 (Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377)](https://superuser.com/questions/1195097/bluetooth-stopped-working-in-windows-10-qualcomm-atheros-qca9377)

**BUT** my problem is , this has happened to me three days in a row now. With a few other occurrences this year (laptop is 1.5 year old)

- Every now and then I realize my paired Bluetooth devices won't connect to my Laptop on turning them on
- On checking the Bluetooth devices menu in Settings everything looks ok, so I try to toggle Bluetooth ... aaand fml the *toggle disappears*
- If I then check device manager, everything is fine - bluetooth still shows
- but if I try disable/re-enable or try to reinstall drivers, bluetooth disappears altogether!

Also this appears:

```
Universal Serial Bus controllers > Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed).
```

The only way I am able to fix it is a non-answer response from the thread. It goes like this (I don't uninstall my existing Atheros bluetooth driver)

- Uninstall the 'unknown USB device'
- Shutdown computer
- Remove power for a minute or two
- Boot up again and Bluetooth is back!

Nothing else works:

- Disable / uninstall 'unknown USB device' => scan for hardware changes
- Uninstall all existing bluetooth drivers => install latest Atheros drivers
- Any number of restarts in between any combination of above steps.

Want to find a root cause, as this is getting pretty annoying!

Comment: Anything in Event Viewer?

Comment: Had not checked it before but I see a lot of 'WHEA-Logger' warnings about "A corrected hardware error has occurred" - source : Advanced error reporting (PCI Express)

Comment: Also, around the time of issue, "The local Bluetooth adapter has failed in an undetermined manner and will not be used. The driver has been unloaded." Source 'BTHUSB'

Comment: Now that I've seen my event viewer riddled with WHEA-logger event id 17 events , I'm gonna go down that rabbit hole (and it seems to be a really deep one) through google and windows support forums. These seem to be  driver / wifi or bluetooth adapter related.

Comment: Good luck Agent.

Comment: What news from the West?